# Would this stop Cross-site request forgery attempt?

Tags: php, security, csrf

I am thinking of a way to stop Cross-site request forgery attack as part of my secure coding class.

I am thinking that if I could block attempt to connect to my website with different address than one that page is located at... But would that work? If not, what would be better approach?

What if I did this as my attempt:

```
// assuming my page is still on 192.168.195.128
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && 
    $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] != "192.168.195.128")
{
    echo 'Cross-site request forgery attempt!';
}
else
{
    // continue normal execution
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that won't do anything to stop CSRF.

What you need is a token of some kind that is passed to the user to be sent back on a form submission.  This token should only be used once, and in a specific place.

CSRF works by sending a generic request to a different site than the user is currently on, generally taking advantage of the fact that they are already authenticated and what not on the site being attacked.  These requests come from the user's browser and look just like normal requests.  You can check the referrer, but a simple token passed in a form is generally considered better.

Comment: I would say - Never trust referrer, use only token.

Comment: To clarify, all request data can be spoofed, which includes the `Referer:` header.  The reason a token is better is that it has to be sent to the client first, giving the legit client code knowledge of something that evil code doesn't know about.

Comment: @Brad, one quick question about my code. Assuming attacker isn't interested in spoofing any header information... What effect would have the code I posted on CSRF? Meaning supposing attacker would try to post a request from different address as proper CSRF (from page from 192.168.195.1 address and hidden fields [and all]) attack... I'm just interested why my code wouldn't work. As I don't have much experience with PHP, would HTTP_HOST return 192.168.195.1 address and disallow POST request??

Comment: Your code has absolutely no effect at all.  All you're doing is verifying that the server your code is running on is the one you expect it to be, which should generally always be the case.  If you want to verify anything, you would verify that the `Referer` header is from your site.  If headers weren't spoofed, then that `Referer` would be from your own domain, meaning that the request wasn't from another page.